# Insert/Update mass records SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, bigdata

I have a problem with a lot of records that I have to process. I want to know which is the fastest way to do it.

**My problem description:**

I have a table (let's call it `FooTable`) with more than `2.000.000.000 records` with an id (let's call it `FooId`). I need to sum my `FooId` to check how many time it repeats. This table is growing every second because it's like a log table.

**Procedures that I tried:**

Read blocks of `600 records` of my `FooTable`, process all the records (doing the sum of each `FooId`) doing a `GroupBy` by code and store the results in another table (let's call it `FooResults`). This `FooResults` new table was created in the same schema of the old one, `FooTable`.

**Procedures results:**

Each block reading is very quick as is the data processing. The problem is the saving. My calculations say that this will take about 27 days. This is obviously too much.

**Tests:**

I did a test with `100.000 records`. After processing this data results in `6000 records`, approximately, the reading took 32 seconds; the processing took 32 milliseconds; and the saving took 18 minutes.

**Future tries:**

I'm thinking about trying to create a table in another schema, doing an unique reading operation of all the records until the last one, process all data in memory and add it to this new table. This new table would be with index disabled.
Try sql without using Entity Framework.
Try to use Batch.

**Technologies used:**

- C#
- Entity Framework
- Sql Server 2012

**Edit 1:**

The data contained in this table is critical data that will be used to analytics and can't be deleted.

Comment: One good thing about the logs is that they are not critical data and can be deleted after some amount of time, like 30 days.

Comment: The problem is that this is critical data that will be used to analytics. It can't be deleted. I will edit my question.

Comment: You could use SqlBulkCopy https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are you doing other special processing in C# apart from the `GroupBy`, or require the intermediate data outside the DB? My point being, I would definitely look at running the process as a stored procedure (your future "try sql without EF"). For reasonable amounts of data and processing, EF and other ORMs generally just don't perform. SQL is set-based, .NET is not, so do set-based operations in the DB.

Comment: Also, slightly separate point - if it is being updated every second, maybe look at a schema-bound view which does the FooID counting, so you have a "realitime" view of the data. It might perform like a dog or lock everything I don't know, but might be worth a look

Comment: make sure that entity framework is not loading your data in applicaiton and then performing sum and saving back to db. check for queries executed by EF. `context.Database.Log = Debug.WriteLine;` will log all the queries to Visual Studio debug window.

Comment: @Rhumborl Thank you for your comments, it will help.

Comment: @ArjunVachhani Thank you for your comment. That line `context.Database.Log = Debug.WriteLine;` will help a lot for other things not related hehehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run this as a query in the database.  If you want to check one such value:

```
select count(*)
from table t
where fooid = @foodid;
```

Create an index on `table(fooid)`, and this will run quite quickly, even on 2 billion rows.

If you need to find the counts for all foo ids:

```
select fooid, count(*)
from table t (with nolock)
group by fooid;
```

This will take longer, but not 27 days, and it can also take advantage of the index.  In general, you want to do this type of processing inside the database, not by bringing the data back to the application.

You might want to consider whether you want to run these queries on a live table that is being used for inserts.  The `selects` and `inserts` can slow things down.  You might consider some sort of replication management so you can have another copy of the database for such analysis.  It would be a best practice to not run such queries on a table that is being updated multiple times per second.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to do that, a replication solution. I didn't know about that nolock option. I will test that.